# PHP: echo £ sign before a variable displays an unwanted character

Tags: php

```
echo "£$price";
```

Displays:

```
Â£35
```

How can I get rid of that unwanted char?

Comment: try to change encoding of your page to utf8

Comment: @FaceOfJock make it an answer and show how to make a page utf8 (including hte right `header` command)

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka answer added.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't serve your content as `utf-8`.
Do this by setting the correct header :

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

In addition to be really sure the browser understands, add this HTML Meta tag in your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to convert that character to an html entity.

```
echo htmlentities('£').$price;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or instead of £ with HTML output you can always write

```
&pound;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your editor is probably set to save your files in utf8, whcih is fine.

The browser may use a different encoding by default. You can hint te browser by using this html5 meta tag:

```
<meta charset="utf8">
```

Or the older non-html5 equivalent

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

You can also specify the charset as a HTTP Header, using `header()`:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

It also doesn't hurt to read [Joel on charsets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).